# Multivariate Chain Rule Dimensionality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Say you have three functions, $f, g, h$:
$$f(x): \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$g(y): \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$$
$$h(z): \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$$

I want to take the derivative of $f(g(h(z)))$ with respect to $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If I apply the chain rule, I find that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}$$
But here's where I'm confused. I think that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times 1}$, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, and these dimensions clearly don't match up in the product. I was expecting that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: In the way you wrote the chain rule, it is customary to identify the derivative of a function, say $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, with a $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: The derivative of $h(z) \colon \  \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ is a linear mapping (or linear operator): $\dfrac{\partial{h}}{\partial{z}} \in \mathcal{L}( \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k).$